# Revenge attitude: is it innate or acquired in human

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, personality

I am trying to understand what is the root cause for revenge? I understand anger is caused by the gap between expectation/anticipation and the reality. But as to revenge, I am not satisfied just with identity related or social order maintenance or reciprocity. While resources pointing to the direction of getting started, any valuable input, views, opinions and research outcomes would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open access sources from Google Scholar:

Jackson, J. C., Choi, V. K., & Gelfand, M. J. (2019). Revenge: A multilevel review and synthesis. Annual Review of Psychology, 70, 319-345. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-psych-010418-103305

Lambert, A. J., Eadeh, F. R., & Hanson, E. J. (2019). Anger and its consequences for judgment and behavior: Recent developments in social and political psychology. Advances in Experimental Social Psychology, 60, 103-173.  https://psyarxiv.com/svcux/download?format=pdf

Comment: Thank you for the sources. Could you include a very concise quote which best represents an answer to this question?

Comment: @StevenJeuris.  The question was "Could anyone suggest me a resource or lead to get started in this line?".  Is there anything else for me to respond to?

Comment: @TonyMobbs. I have edited my question for the experts to post their valuable views, points opinions and research outcomes.

Comment: @TonyMobbs the question title.  Innate or acquired? (or unknown, or a mix,....)